# Display a variable when a select box option is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For example, the select box

```
<select>
  <option selected="" value="">Please Select</option>
  <option value='txt'>Text</option>
  <option value='int'>Numbers</option>
  <option value='bool' >Boolean</option>
</select>
```

has a string

```
$messageList=array ( 'txt'=>'text message', 'int'=>'int message',
                     'bool'=>'bool message');
```

What i would like to achieve is to  display correspond message when the optition is select?

Comment: Display the corresponding message how?  In an alert box?  In another element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know php, but First I think you need to use `json_encode` to convert php array to a javascript object. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

```
<?php
   $messageList=array ( 'txt'=>'text message', 'int'=>'int message','bool'=>'bool message');

   echo var msgs = json_encode($messageList);
?>
```

And then in javascript,

```
$('select').change (function () { 
    alert(msgs[$(this).val()]);
});
```

Also you need a `class/id` for the select. because the above code will triggered when you change the option of any select box in the page.

Comment: @user782104 As I mentioned earlier, I am not a php guy.. but if you have the database return has a similar result then the `json_encode` will give you the javascript object which you can use it in your javascript.

Comment: instead of alert how can i display on screen like a html content?

Comment: @user782104 depends on where you want to display. Lets say you have a simple div like `<div id='showMsg' ></div>` in your html, then you can `$('#showMsg').html(msgs[$(this).val()]));`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the array you posted was meant to be a JavaScript object (it seems you were using PHP's associative array notation):

```
​var sel = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0],
    $messageList= {
    'txt' : 'text message',
    'int' : 'int message',
    'bool' : 'bool message'
    };

sel.onchange = function(){
    var selected = this.value;
    alert($messageList[selected]);
};​​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/KEGdJ/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with jQuery:

```
$messageList= { 'txt':'text message', 'int':'int message','bool':'bool message' };

$('#choices').change( function() { alert( $messageList[ $(this).val() ] ); } );​
```

JFiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/yCHqy/